# EXT2 - boundaries of group descriptor table

Tags: filesystems

I have to write a CLI program for university that takes in a drive formatted using the ext2 file system. I have to recover certain files. After reading [this](https://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html) article I still have one question left. When reading out the Descriptor Table of a Block Group right after the Superblock, I don't know when to stop. If I understand the FS correctly it allocates in blocks. So if the table does not fit into one block, a whole second block is allocated for the table. But how do I know how many blocks were allocated for the table?

The Superblock contains the fields `s_blocks_count` and `s_blocks_per_group` but they are only helpful if I have 0% fragmentation. I would not be able to guess the number of groups if for example, I have 8 groups each only with one data block due to fragmentation.

Then there is `s_first_data_block` which I thought would be the exact information I need

```
decriptor_table_range = end_of_superblock..(s_first_data_block - block_bitmap - inode_bitmap - inode_table)
```

The size of the inode table is defined by `s_inodes_per_group` and `s_inode_size`. But the article states that `s_first_data_block` Is only 0 or 1.

> 32bit value identifying the first data block, in other word the id of
> the block containing the superblock structure.
>
> Note that this value is always 0 for file systems with a block size
> larger than 1KB, and always 1 for file systems with a block size of
> 1KB. The superblock is always starting at the 1024th byte of the disk,
> which normally happens to be the first byte of the 3rd sector.

So this does not help either. The only chance I see is getting the size of the drive and checking how many groups I can fit into the drive while taking the growing group descriptor table into account. But what if I have a .img file mounted as a drive? I think this file grows dynamically, so here I don't know what the max size is.

So how do I know, how many blocks were used for the block descriptor table, i.e. how many block groups are there?

**EDIT:**

I'm sorry but I made a big mistake. Even though I read the article I thought `s_blocks_count` contained the number of blocks currently used. But it contains the TOTAL number including the free blocks. So `s_blocks_count / s_blocks_per_group` actually does work.

> 32bit value indicating the total number of blocks in the system
> including all used, free and reserved. This value must be lower or
> equal to (s_blocks_per_group * number of block groups). It can be
> lower than the previous calculation if the last block group has a
> smaller number of blocks than s_blocks_per_group du to volume size. It
> must be equal to the sum of the blocks defined in each block group.

Comment: Please add your edit as an answer — if you find the answer to your own question, it’s fine to answer it yourself.